# Cross-platform best practice: whether to include data files in your project when they are usually distributed as packages on Linux

Tags: cross-platform

I am developing a program that has to perform spellcheck/morphology analysing, necessitating  the use of myspell/hunspell dictionaries. These dictionary files are usually distributed as Linux packages, e.g. myspell-en, myspell-de, etc. So on Linux I should just try finding them at standard locations, such as `/usr/share/hunspell`. The problem is, should I include these files in my project structure if I am to release on Windows?